# Forge deployment clears .env file

Tags: laravel, deployment, environment-variables, forge, envoyer.io

Ok, i'm not sure i've got this figured out quite right yet.

Everywhere i look, everyone says not to include your .env file in your repo. This makes sense. What I don't understand is how i'm meant to add the .env to a deployed site.

I'm building a laravel app and trying to deploy through forge. This much works, and then i edit the .env through the forge interface. This seems like a better approach indeed, except whenever another deploy goes through, the .env file gets wiped. So is there a better way to do this or is there a setting i need to check?

Comment: I have this problem too:(

Comment: @KótaPéter see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i've found two solutions. One for forge, and one for envoyer.

For forge, I created a recipe that makes the .env file, and this seems to run when forge deploys.

However, the process is different if you use envoyer. In your project, navigate to the servers tab and click manage environment. This allows you to enter your environment variables and feels like a much cleaner way to do this.

Hope this helps any future people struggling with this!

Comment: Can you show me your forge recipe? How can I make .env from recpie?

Comment: It's just a bash script:

echo "
DB_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
(etc.)
" > site-folder.com/.env

Comment: (Multiple lines is fine, it just won't let me format it that way for a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this video says it will happen magically. The only thing you need to keep in mind that you need to have your set up with done first. Next time you deploy, symlink will be added automatically.